# How to add 0's to an int

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, number-formatting

I have the following SQL query

```
SELECT MAX(averageSales)
FROM (
    SELECT AVG(TotalSale) AS averageSales
    FROM [Practice].[dbo].[Sales]
    GROUP BY CAST(SalesPerson AS NVARCHAR(100))
) AS Query1;
```

I get the result as `250` but I want to display the result as `250.0000`. I have looked at `RIGHT` and `LEFT` function for SQL but have not been able to figure it out yet. 
The data type for averageSales is an int.

I tried the following approach as well

```
SELECT 
    MAX(averageSales), 
    CAST(MAX(averageSales) AS decimal(4,4))
FROM (
    SELECT AVG(TotalSale) AS averageSales 
    FROM [Practice].[dbo].[Sales]
    GROUP BY CAST(SalesPerson AS NVARCHAR(100))
) AS Query1;
```

but this results in

> Arithmetic overflow error converting int to data type numeric.

Comment: Are you sure you want that column to be an `int`? It sounds like a currency field..

Comment: @Blorgbeard, This was a practice exam I saw online and wanted to implement the solution myself. So I copied whatever they gave me. I would not personally make this an int column.

Comment: Your `decimal(4,4)` declares a number with a TOTAL of 4 digits (the first '4'), of which 4 are after the decimal point (the second '4').  That means it can handle anything from 0.0000 to 0.9999, which is why you get that overflow error when trying to cast a value of 250.  The cast would not produce an error if you made it a `decimal(8,4)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `FORMAT(..., '#.0000')`:

```
SELECT FORMAT(MAX(averageSales), '#.0000') FROM 
(
    SELECT AVG(TotalSale) AS averageSales FROM [Practice].[dbo].[Sales]
    GROUP BY CAST(SalesPerson AS NVARCHAR(100))
) AS Query1;
```

Comment: Even tough this answer is correct, I would strongly suggest rendering the output in the front end.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CAST` with `DECIMAL` not `NVARCHAR`

```
GROUP BY CAST(SalesPerson as DECIMAL(8,4))
```